# How to find list of programs that can handle a file extension in node.js in WIndows?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a file explorer in node.js.

I want to know how I can find a list of programs that can handle a file extension in Windows (like it does in Windows built in file explorer when you right-click a file and hover over "open with" option).

Comment: File extension handlers are stored in the Windows registry.  You will have to find a way to read the Windows registry and then find the right place in the registry to get this info (something you can find with a Google search).  Also, there are NPM modules that can access the windows registry from node.js.

Comment: See I've looked at the registry and seen some answers regarding this, but struggling to find the programs that open a certain extension